# Не обрабатывается php-скрипт после символа ->

Tags: php

Есть код, хранящийся в БД:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/global.inc.php';

$username = "";
$password = "";
$password_confirm = "";
$email = "";
$error = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit-form'])) { 

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password_confirm = $_POST['password-confirm'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


$success = true;

$userTools = new UserTools();
if($userTools -> checkUsernameExists($username))
{
$error .= "That username is already taken.<br/> \n\r";
$success = false;
}

if($password != $password_confirm) {
$error .= "Passwords do not match.<br/> \n\r";
$success = false;
}

if($success)
{

$data['username'] = $username;
$data['password'] = md5($password);
$data['email'] = $email;

$newUser = new User($data);

$newUser->save(true);

$userTools -> login($username, $password);

header("Location: welcome.php");
}
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="forma.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<form action="registration.php" method="POST" id="loginform">

<div class="field">
<label>Имя пользователя:</label>
<div class="input"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username;?>" name="username"></div>
</div>

<div class="field">
<label>Пароль:</label>
<div class="input"><input type="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>" name="password"></div>
</div>

<div class="field">
<label>Подтверждение пароля:</label>
<div class="input"><input type="password" value="<?php echo $password_confirm;?>" name="password-confirm"></div>
</div>

<div class="field">
<label>E-mail:</label>
<div class="input"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $email;?>" name="email"></div>
</div>

<div class="submit">
<button type="submit" value="Register" name="submit-form">Зарегистрироваться</button>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Дело в том, что мне необходимо вывести его на страницу. Но выводится всё это дело почему-то только до символа обращения к методу класса:

```
$userTools = new UserTools();
if($userTools -> checkUsernameExists($username))
```

После стрелки код читается браузером как обычный текст и таким образом выводится на странице. Как с этим бороться?

UserTools:

```
<?php
require_once 'User.class.php';
require_once 'DB.class.php';

class UserTools {


    public function login($username, $password)

    {

        $hashedPassword = md5($password);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND
                password = '$hashedPassword'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION["user"] = serialize(new User(mysql_fetch_assoc($result)));
            $_SESSION["login_time"] = time();
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = 1;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        unset($_SESSION['login_time']);
        unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function checkUsernameExists($username) {
        $result = mysql_query("select id from user where username='$username'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }


    public function get($id)
    {
        $db = new DB();
        $result = $db->select('user', "id = $id");
        return new User($result);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Что значит "вывести" на страницу? Именно вывести или все-таки выполнить и вывести результат?

Comment: @АлексейГерасимов, может стоит экранировать текст перед сохранением в бд?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev нет, выполнить и вывести.

Comment: А ошибки есть какие? В apache error.log? Я думаю сейчас уже время перестать использовать md5, если вариантов нет то перейдите на sha1. А лучше http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php или http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Да покажите код UserTools (особенно конструктор);

Comment: @E_p 
Ошибок в логе нет. Насчёт md5, это не имеет значения, код без базы данных прекрасно работал. Код UserTools приложу выше в посте.

Comment: А какую часть он начинает печатать как текст? Точное начало. Просто похоже вы закрыли `?>` раньше времени где то в одном из ваших файлов. Вообше  хорошая практика для PHP не закрывать `?>` в конце чистых php файлов.

Comment: @E_p Вот в этой строке: 
if($userTools -> checkUsernameExists($username)) 
Сразу после -> (тобишь её он воспринимает, а всё, что после - нет).

Comment: Мне вот интересно, почему код `php` должен обрабатываться, если это достается как plain text? вот вы достаете это всё из базы и дальше что, это через `echo` выводите или как? Каким образом куда вы вставляете это?

Comment: @АлексейГерасимов, в браузере нажмите правую кнопку мыши, и кликните просмотр кода страницы, там вы увидите что всё до -> тоже выводиться как текст(если вы код через `echo` или `print` выводите)

Answer (score 1):

**Не храните код в БД. Никогда так не делайте.** Для этого есть куча вариантов template сборщиков, от XML до объектных.
Попробуйте заэкранировать символ `->` вот так `-\>`, посмотрите, что страница выведет.

Comment: Сначала попробовал заменить '$userTools -> checkUsernameExists($username)' на true, код стал читаться ровно до следующей такой же ->. А если заэкранировать, то всё по-прежнему.

Comment: попробуйте заэхать код, и посмотрите, что за символы он выдает в местах `->`. Если что, реплейсить кривые интерпретации